# How to compare one row in Pandas Dataframe to all other rows in the same Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a csv file with in which I want to compare each row with all other rows. I want to do a linear regression and get the r^2 value for the linear regression line and put it into a new matrix. I'm having trouble finding a way to iterate over all the other rows (it's fine to compare the primary row to itself).

I've tried using .iterrows but I can't think of a way to define the other rows once I have my primary row using this function.

UPDATE: Here is a solution I came up with. Please let me know if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

```
    def bad_pairs(df, limit):
      list_fluor = list(combinations(df.index.values, 2))
      final = {}
      for fluor in list_fluor:
        final[fluor] = (r2_score(df.xs(fluor[0]), 
    df.xs(fluor[1])))
      bad_final = {}
      for i in final:
        if final[i] > limit:
          bad_final[i] = final[i]
      return(bad_final)
```

My data is a pandas DataFrame where the index is the name of the color and there is a number between 0-1 for each detector (220 columns).

I'm still working on a way to make a new pandas Dataframe from a dictionary with all the values (final in the code above), not just those over the limit.

Comment: Can you clarify with an example what you need?. I think what you want to do can be achieved without explicitly iterating.

Comment: I've added to the original post. Does this clear things up?

Comment: Post your code and data here. Don't post screenshots.

Comment: You don't need `.iterrows()`, you can use `.apply()`. You want to sweep the `r2_score` function on each row in `fluor_final` against every other row. But please **post your actual code and a snippet of data here, not screenshots.**

Comment: You need to **post your code and data (here, not as screenshots)**. Otherwise this fails SO requirements to be MCVE ([mcve]).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.